# Speed up mysql select query

Tags: mysql

Am I missing any tricks to speed up this select query? the query is grabbing the location data as the users types it in, its auto filled.

```
$q = mysqli_real_escape_string(strtolower($_GET["q"]));

if (!$q) return;
    $sql = "SELECT us_city AS city, us_abv AS state, us_zip AS zip 
        FROM search_us
        WHERE us_zip LIKE '$q%' OR us_city 
        LIKE '$q%' GROUP BY us_abv, us_city, us_zip LIMIT 15";
    $places = mysqli_query($sql);
    while($place = mysqli_fetch_array($places)) {
    echo "$place[city], $place[state], $place[zip]\n"; 
}
```

Comment: I only see the possibility of an sql-injection ;)

Comment: You _might_ improve performance by indexing the `us_zip` and `us_city` columns - you'd have to try it. A better approach might be to cache (in $_SESSION[]) the result of the search after the first letter is typed and getting subsequent results from that instead of the database.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but why do you need GROUP BY without any aggregation function? Other than that it is really hard to say if you don't explain what is your problem. What is the size of your data? Do you use any indexes?

Comment: @Enthusiasmus the data is escaped see `$q`

Comment: @zero323 us_city and us_zip are indexed and 43628 entries which double since its scanning city and zip for each entry

Comment: If I understand correctly you expect zip code or city name as an input. If it is the case you can perform simple check if provided value can be a zip code and completely remove irrelevant part of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR is often handled poorly by the optimizer, because only one index is chosen, so only one half of the OR can benefit from an index-based search.

Splitting the query into two unioned queries usually improves performance, because a different index can be used for each half, so effectively two indexes can be used - one for each side of the OR.

Also, your query has an unnessessaru `group by` that should be removed.

Try this query (without irrelevant app code):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    us_city AS city,
    us_abv AS state,
    us_zip AS zip 
  FROM search_us
  WHERE us_city LIKE '$q%'
  UNION
  SELECT
    us_city AS city,
    us_abv AS state,
    us_zip AS zip 
  FROM search_us
  WHERE us_zip LIKE '$q%') x
LIMIT 15
```

The LIMIT clause must be applied to the result if the union.

Make sure you have separate indexes on us_city and us_zip.